# Not able to see docker task in order to run gradle build docker getting error task docker not found

Tags: docker, gradle, dockerfile, build.gradle

Hi I am using gradle palantir plugin in order to build a docker image from dockerfile
when i run the `gw build docker` its throwing `Task 'docker' not found in project ':hop-service'.`

when i ran `gw tasks`  i m not able to see the docker tasks not sure what mistakes i have done build.gradle file below is my gradle file

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
          url 'https://artifactory.codetest.com/artifactory/sf-microservices-hop'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.codetest.platform.foundation:platform-build-template:1.0.37.BUILD"
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.7.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.7.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'com.palantir.docker' version '0.22.1'
}

ext{
    appProjects=['hop-service']
    mapstructVersion = '1.3.1.Final'
    annotationProcessVersion = '0.21'
}

apply from: project.buildscript.classLoader.getResource("scripts/build.gradle")

subprojects {
  version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
  group = 'com.xyz'
}
docker {
    name "mycoolapp"
    dockerfile file('Dockerfile')
    copySpec.from(jar).rename(".*","app.jar")
    buildArgs(['JAR_FILE': "app.jar"])
}
```

Dockerfile code

```
    FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
ARG JAR_FILE
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got a solution to this 
Actually there are two build.gradle in project directory one is parent build gradle which i have mentioned above and another is child project build.gradle.

I have to mention these line of code in child project not in parent project after providing in child project build.gradle now i see docker tasks

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.7.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.7.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'com.palantir.docker' version '0.22.1'
}
docker {
    name "mycoolapp"
    dockerfile file('Dockerfile')
    copySpec.from(jar).rename(".*","app.jar")
    buildArgs(['JAR_FILE': "app.jar"])
}
```